# Can't make intel hd 4000 drivers to work

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, xserver

After replacing my `xserver` with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

I can't get my `Intel HD 4000` card to work in `12.04`. Or to be more specific, I can't get the effects that I had with unity working again. Even changing workspaces looks ugly now. 
I've searched this forum and googled everything about `intel hd 4000 drivers` + `ubuntu` but no luck. Everything I found was about linux 13.04. Please help me. How to get my good looking system back?

I've installed `mesa-utils` but System Details still doesn't recognize my graphics card.

[image: Details]
[image: Details2]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following packages installed?

```
$ dpkg -l | grep intel | awk '{print $2}'
intel-gpu-tools
libdrm-intel1:amd64
libdrm-intel1:i386
xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

It's working fine for me, and with some of the compiz effects.

I'm using 13.04 but it worked fine in the 12.10 as well. And I actually had some little issue during the migration but not big deal.

Comment: intel-gpu-tools
libdrm-intel1
libdrm-intel1:i386
libva-intel-vaapi-driver
whois
xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-quantal

Yup, i don't get libdrm-intel1:amd64 but when i try to install it... it says it's already installed.